# Spark explode in Scala - Add exploded column to the row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a Spark Dataframe with the following contents:

| Name | E1 | E2 | E3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 4 | 5 | 6 |

I need the various `E` columns to become rows in a new column as shown below:

| Name | value | EType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 4 | E1 |
| abc | 5 | E2 |
| abc | 6 | E3 |

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59867060/scala-spark-explode-multiple-columns-pairs-into-rows)
gave me the idea of using `explode` and I now have the following code:

```
df.select($"Name", explode(array("E1", "E2", "E3")).as("value"))
```

The above code gives me the Name and value columns I need, but I still need a way to add in the EType column based on which value in the array passed to `explode` is being used to populate that particular row.

Output of the above code:

| Name | value |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 4 |
| abc | 5 |
| abc | 6 |

How can I add the Etype column?

(I am using Spark 2.2 with Scala)

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to melt Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670103/how-to-melt-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stack` function for this particular case.

```py
df.selectExpr('Name', "stack(3, E1, 'E1', E2, 'E2', E3, 'E3')").toDF('Name', 'value', 'EType').show()

df.selectExpr('Name', "stack(3, E1, 'E1', E2, 'E2', E3, 'E3')").toDF('Name', 'value', 'EType').show()
df.selectExpr('Name', "stack(3, E1, 'E1', E2, 'E2', E3, 'E3')").toDF('Name', 'value', 'EType').show()
+----+-----+-----+
|Name|value|EType|
+----+-----+-----+
| abc|    4|   E1|
| abc|    5|   E2|
| abc|    6|   E3|
+----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of exploding just value, you can explode a `struct` that contains the name of the column and its content, as follows:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{array, col, explode, lit, struct}

val result = df
  .select(
    col("name"), 
    explode(array(
      df.columns.filterNot(_ == "name").map(c => struct(lit(c).as("EType"), col(c).alias("value"))): _*
    ))
  )
  .select("name", "col.*")
```

With your input you will get as `result` dataframe:

```
+----+-----+-----+
|name|EType|value|
+----+-----+-----+
|abc |E1   |4    |
|abc |E2   |5    |
|abc |E3   |6    |
+----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use melt operation here.

Note: Melt functionality is not present in pyspark, you need write that util function.

You can go thought this answer on how to implement melt function [How to melt Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670103/how-to-melt-spark-dataframe)